# Wso2 Data service giving java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, wso2

I created a web service using wso2 data service. But when I try to test it it gives below error.

Below is the screenshot of the error.

[image: Image of error.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this error, because you haven't defined the result of your select query. When you define a SELECT query, you are going to retrieve a resultset from the query. So you need to define the result using the output parameters.

In the Add Query page there is a section called 'Result (Output Mapping)' where you can define the resut.

Alternatively you can define the query with column names (ex: SELECT name, age from Student) and then just click on 'Generate Responses' which automatically generate the response[1].

[1]http://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS301/Generate+Response